# How does inspirational expertise function?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

I am not sure how this investogator talent ability is supposed to function.
How many times can the swift action be used per creature?
Is it required to make knowledge check for each swift action use, if the same opponent can be targeted multiple times?
Anything else i should know about?

To me it seems that you can make a knowledge check during your turn (but knowledge checks should happen when you see the target?) and immediately use the swift action once, and never again for that monster, because it is tied to that knowledge check.

Background info: I am a GM and one of my players plays investigator amd has this talent picked.

Comment: Would you mind adding your understanding of the feature? I'm having difficulty understanding what about it seems complicated without essentially reproducing it along the Inspiration class feature.

Comment: Added my interpretation of the talent use.

Answer (score 2):

### You are correct

Inspirational Expertise provides a 1-round buff that can be applied after a successful Knowledge check. Per the Knowledge skill

> **Try Again:** No. The check represents what you know, and thinking about a topic a second time doesn’t let you know something that you never learned in the first place.

Without another way to accomplish this, such as [Kirin Style](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kirin%20Style), (which may or may not work, up to you as the GM, and would be a 2-round combo considering it also uses their Swift) They cannot roll Knowledge about that creature again. For further insight, and a possible recommendation to your player, see [Studied Expertise](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Studied%20Expertise).

> You can spend one use of inspiration as a swift action to grant allies within 30 feet that can hear you a +4  insight bonus on attack rolls against one type of monster for 1 round, provided you succeeded at a Knowledge check to identify that type of monster’s special powers or vulnerabilities **no more than 1 minute earlier**.

Studied Expertise can be used repeatedly for the 10 rounds following a successful Knowledge check, directly building off of the Talent.